# Debugging jetty daemon process in gradle

Tags: jetty, gradle, daemon

Using a JettyRun task, it's easy to debug. You can merely add something like `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=12233,server=y,suspend=n` to your GRADLE_OPTS and hook up to the gradle process itself.

However, if you run a JettyRun task with daemon = true, this doesn't work. Example of one such task:

```
task jettyRunDaemon (type: JettyRun) {
    contextPath = '/'
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    webAppSourceDirectory = file('src/test/webapp')
    daemon = true
}
```

I've tried some other things, such as setting the `org.gradle.jvmargs` with a similar thing as above, to no avail. How can I get the debug args sent into the daemon process?

Answer (score 1):

I would give `org.gradle.jvmargs` another shot. Try putting the following into a `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4001
```

I'm using this with gradle 1.8 and I'm able to attach and step through code.