# Debugging IntelliJ gradle jettyRun app - where is jetty directory?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, jetty, gradle

I have a gradle jettyRun configuration that I would like to debug through intellij. Where do I find the value for the jetty directory since I'm running jetty through gradle?

Comment: AFAIK Gradle is running embedded version of Jetty. Just download the same version and add as home.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that but got an error trying to connect to it. I'll verify that I have the right version.

Comment: Are you able to attach IntelliJ to jetty debugger? That comes before version.

Comment: When I try to attach to the debugger, I get the error: Debugger failed to attach: recv failed during handshake: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: Using the same ports? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315398/how-to-run-jetty-via-gradle-in-debug-mode

Comment: I believe so, yes. I see the message both in intellij and in my jetty task, so it looks like they are trying to communicate.

Comment: Can you try to attach with jdb? `jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:hostname=localhost,port=<port>`

Comment: When I ran that, it gave me the output `Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable`
`Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable`
`Initializing jdb ...`
>, so it looks like I can connect (I ran `threads` and it printed out the threads)

Comment: When you run gradle with --info, can you see jetty version?

Comment: It doesn't say the specific version, no, but I'm using gradle 1.10 which I believe uses Jetty 6.1.25. Anyway, I'm going to take a break from working on this - I can debug with Tomcat, so it's not a huge deal. Appreciate the effort though.